# Egit "*" symbol?

Tags: git, egit

Hiho,

I'm using the egit plugin for eclipse.

What does this Symbol "*" mean over the icon of a file?

The file is committed but with "git status" the file is marked with "changes to be commited" but with "git diff" happens nothing:/

Here's a screenshot:

[image: http://imgur.com/hUyQN.png]

greetings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it means the file is staged for commit, see the section [Icon decorations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Icon_Decorations) in the eclipse wiki

> - staged - The resource has changes which have been added to the index. Note that adding changes to the index is currently possible only in the commit dialog via the context menu of a resource.
> - partially-staged - The resource has changes which are added to the index and additional changes in the working tree that neither reached the index nor have been committed to the repository.

that is, files which are already tracked by git and changes to them were staged with `git add (-p) <file>`